# How to resolve unregister_netdevice: waiting for dummy_lo to become free. Usage count = 1 in Linux Kernel Version : 4.9.79?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, busybox

While doing rmmod of net driver I am getting error as `unregister_netdevice: waiting for dummy_lo to become free. Usage count = 1`, this error keeps on printing on the console and the only way to recover the system is to issue power cycle to the system or to give a cold reboot. Earlier I was using Linux kernel version 3.10.85 and this issue was not seen. But after upgrading to Kernel Version 4.9.79 started seeing this issue. While going through this problem on internet I found several bugs reported as part of docker bring up, but here I am not using a docker, here I am using busy-box with Linux Kernel 4.9.79.

While going through git hub page of Linus Torvalds found this commit `https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/ee60ad219f5c7c4fb2f047f88037770063ef785f`, but as per going through the commit, found that it just solves the issue associated to ip del command.

dummy_lo interface info:

> -bash-4.3# ip link show dev dummy_lo
>
> 23: dummy_lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode
> DEFAULT group default
> link/loopback

Any help would be really helpful! Let me know if any more details are required to understand this problem, I will provide the same.

Comment: As of today the v4.9.y has the latest v4.9. **257**. Can you reproduce the issue there?

Comment: Sure @0andriy let me try with the latest version and check. Thanks!